# YCSB full table scan on HBase?

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I want to analyze the full table scan performance of HBase, but after reading the source code of YCSB, I find that the scan length is randomly generated. Can YCSB carry out a full table scan of HBase table to analyze the performance?
Thanks~

Comment: You could write your own custom workload for this, where the scan length is fixed. Modifying the core workload would be pretty easy.